# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' after trying to load an angular website

Tags: angular, safari

I receive this error in safari on my iPhone after trying to access an angular website:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

The website is then just stuck on a white screen without providing more information.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remembered, that i once had the same problem trying to open an ionic app. I fixed the problem by lowering the `target` version in my `tsconfig.json` file:

[image]

In my case i had to go from `es2020` to `es2018` to make it work, since i have installed an older ios version (13.3.1) on my test device.

I hope it helps some of you!